# What does it mean bounded for a measurable set?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

It is right that a set $G$ open and measurable, is bounded if $\mu(G) < \infty$ where $\mu$ is the measure relative to the measurable space?

Answer (score 4):

I would say that "bounded" is not a concept that applies to measure, it applies to distance. With measure, if $\mu(g)<\infty$, we say that $G$ "has finite measure".

A **bounded** set, in $\mathbb R^n$, is defined as a set that is a subset of $B(0, M$) for some $M\in\mathbb R$

---

A set in $\mathbb R^n$ can then

1. have finite measure and be bounded (example: $[0,1]\subset\mathbb R$)
2. have finite measure and be unbounded (example: $\mathbb Q\subset\mathbb R$)
3. have infinite measure and be unbounded (example: $[0,\infty)\subset\mathbb R$).

The only thing that is impossible is for a set to have infinite measure and be bounded, because if $X\subset B(0, M)$, then $\mu(X)\leq\mu(B(0,M))<\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, I think that having $\mathbb{R}^n$ as example is helpful. Especially because in the text I'm reading the measure is the Lebesque measure.

Comment: @dual0 Yeah, if you are talking about $\mathbb R^n$, then "bounded" is certainly meant as "subset of some $B(0,M)$.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say so, because I can figure out a set that has a finite measure, and it's unbounded. The set of intervals $$G =\{(n, n+1/2^n) \in \mathbb{R} \; | \; n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$ has a measure $$\mu(G) = 1$$ but it's unbounded.

If a counterexample exists, the statement doesn't hold.